# After installing Ubuntu12.04 LTS, touchpad is not working

Tags: 12.04, dell, touchpad

I have recently installed Ubuntu12.04 on my Dell inspiron 14 3000 Series. After installing Ubuntu12.04(amd 64bit), its touchpad is not working. But its keyboard even wireless Keyboard and mouse is working properly except touchapd.
Here is my xinput list  :

```
 salim@salim:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Integrated_Webcam_HD                      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
 salim@salim:~$
```

Any one help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command `lsusb` gives a result similar to this:

```
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 046d:c068 Logitech, Inc. G500 Laser Mouse
```

So now I have a hardware ID that can be Google searched.

Otherwise, you're using 12.04 and Linux Kernel 3.2- that's pretty old. You could update beautifully by recompiling the latest upstream Kernel, which would probably fix the touchpad issue but it's a lot of extra work. I recompile my Kernel for the extra support and performance increase but not many would find this a suitable answer.

Comment: My system detail: Ubuntu Release 12.04(precise) 64 bit, Kernel linux3.11.0-26-generic, GNOME 3.4.2

Answer (score 0):

It's an old version of Ubuntu but you can still make it run fast using the latest kernel and compiling it. Here are the steps:

```
tar -xvf linux-3.19.tar.xz

cd linux-3.19
```

`make oldconfig`  <-- this will cause many, many questions. Just hit enter through them all.

`make makelocalconfig`  <-- Do this after you plug in all your devices so it will load the modules.

`sudo make xconfig` <-- edit the features and drivers you want to add or remove

```
sudo sudo CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=`getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN` CFLAGS="-O3 -march=bdver2" CXXFLAGS="-O3 -march=bdver2" make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-joel319 kernel_image kernel_headers
```

Change bdver2 to native and change joel319 to whatever tag you want to use.
Now install Grub Customizer to select the kernel and add a bootmenu.

Again, this is probably not the answer you want but it fixes and speeds up the system. I've done it before too when my touchpad didn't work.